# How do I map enums to a class property

Tags: c#, .net, oop, enums

I have an enum that holds feature names such as

```
public enum FeatureNames{
  [Description("Amazing Feature")]
  AmazingFeature,
  [Description("Amazing New Feature")]
  AmazingNewFeature
}
```

I have a domain entity that has properties representing each of the feature which indicates if the feature is turned on or off

```
public class CompanyAccount{
  public bool IsAmazingFeatureEnabled{get;set;}
  public bool IsAmazingNewFeatureEnabled{get;set;}
}
```

This is how the existing application was written and hence I don't want to make drastic changes to DB at this point. So now I am trying to write a genric method that will take in a string or enum value indicating feature and check if the property matching the same feature is enabled or not(true or false).

```
public bool IsEnabled(FeatureNames featureName){
  if(featureName is FeatureNames.AmazingFeature){
    return companyAccount.IsAmazingFeatureEnabled;
  }
  else if(featureName is FeatureNames.AmazingNewFeature){
    return companyAccount.IsAmazingNewFeatureEnabled;
  }
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Can we avoid the if condition?

Comment: Are there more classes than just this `CompanyAccount` that have these kinds of properties, and do they all need to be mapped? Have you considered wrapping these feature flags in a more streamlined config state (be it global or not)?

Comment: @Flater no. All the features belong to Company. So any future features come will be defined in the same class

Comment: If the only focus is `Company` and no other class; I don't understand why you're looking into generics, which in inherently intended to be used for multiple classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) (C# 8.0)

```cs
public bool IsEnabled(FeatureNames featureName) =>
    featureName switch {
        FeatureNames.AmazingFeature => companyAccount.IsAmazingFeatureEnabled,
        FeatureNames.AmazingNewFeature => companyAccount.IsAmazingNewFeatureEnabled,
        _ => false
    };
```

or use a [throw expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#the-throw-expression) in the default case.

```cs
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"{featureName} not implemented")
```

---

Another approach would be to convert the enum into a [flags enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0) and to add a property returning the state as flag set.

```cs
[Flags]
public enum FeatureNames {
    None = 0,
    AmazingFeature = 1,
    AmazingNewFeature = 2 // use powers of 2 for all values
}
```

```cs
public class CompanyAccount{
 public bool IsAmazingFeatureEnabled { get; set; }
 public bool IsAmazingNewFeatureEnabled { get; set; }

 public FeatureNames State {
   get {
     var flags = FeatureNames.None;
     if (IsAmazingFeatureEnabled) flags = flags | FeatureNames.AmazingFeature; 
     if (IsAmazingNewFeatureEnabled) flags = flags | FeatureNames.AmazingNewFeature; 
     return flags;
   }
 }
}
```

Then you can test the state with

```cs
if (companyAccount.State.HasFlag(FeatureNames.AmazingFeature)) ...
```

---

Using the flag enums, we could turn things around and store the state as flags and then put the logic in the Boolean properties (showing just one property here):

```cs
private FeatureNames _state;

public bool IsAmazingFeatureEnabled
{
    get => _state.HasFlag(FeatureNames.AmazingFeature);
    set => _state = value 
        ? _state | FeatureNames.AmazingFeature
        : _state & ~FeatureNames.AmazingFeature;
}
```

Comment: ... Or just leave the default case off and let the compiler insert a default which throws a suitable exception. This has the added benefit of giving you a compiler warning if someone adds a new enum member but doesn't update the switch expression

Comment: This definitely helps. Thanks. I can't use the switch expression as I am on a version that doesn't support it and I can't update but having the state property is something I did.